# FMS VOD streaming: How can I access content that was uploaded to the webroot/vod directory?

Tags: streaming, flash-media-server

I have recently started working with a fresh install of FMS 4.5.0 and am having some issues getting my media to load with the VOD application.

After uploading some of my own FLV/F4V content to "/webroot/vod/", I am currently only able to load the samples from the installation.

Is there some sort of configuration that needs to be made to access my media?

Do I need to create a manifest for each video?

I have been running tests through:
http://www.osmf.org/configurator/fmp/

And have had luck accessing the videos that came with the install by using the following:

Video Source (URL): http://[my host]/vod/sample1_1000kbps.f4v

But when I change this to point to one of my recently uploaded videos it fails everytime.

Another strange note, I was able to play one of the samples but then I changed its name and it was still able to load that one specific video using the same filename when the file's name had changed. This leads me to believe that it isn't really loading the right files or perhaps I am uploading to the wrong directory. But I can't find any other directories that have video in them.

Please let me know if there is any more info you need to help me. I'm fairly new to this and am not sure what to include.

Thanks in advance for any help!

**EDIT: This was a pathing issue.**

Comment: This has been resolved.

Apparently my webroot directory for the server was not set up correctly and after it was pointing to the right directory it was fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been resolved.

Apparently my webroot directory for the server was not set up correctly and after it was pointing to the right directory it was fixed.